# Join Tables SQL Server with duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, duplicates

I have a table

```
col1

1
2
```

and other table

```
col1    col2    col3

1          1    data value one                                    
1          2    data value one                                    
2          3    data value two
```

and I want to join both tables to obtain the following result

```
col1  col2  col3

1       1    data value one
2       3    data value two
```

The second table have duplicates but I need to join only one (randomly). I've tried with Inner Join, Left Join, Right Join and always returns all rows. Actually I use `SQL Server 2008`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` Function along with `ORDER BY NEWID()` To get one random row for each value in col1:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  Col1,
            Col2,
            Col3, 
            [RowNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY NEWID())
    FROM    Table2
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1
        INNER JOIN CTE
            ON CTE.Col1 = table1.Col1
            AND CTE.RowNumber = 1 -- ONLY GET ONE ROW FOR EACH VALUE
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3 from table1 t1
cross apply
(select top 1 col2, col3 from table2 where col1 = t1.col1 order by newid()) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831%28SQL.105%29.aspx) it will eliminate dups, but you sure both rows will contain same data?

Comment: I tried with Distinct too, but the query returns all rows too. With Select Distinct * from table.